# How do I recover files using git?

Tags: git

I committed 2 days ago.  Then, I made changes to some of the files.

However, inside one specific directory, I didn't make any changes to it recently.

Today, I deleted those files using rm * inside that directory.

How can I restore files to that directory using git?

Comment: did you commit your changes? (before and after delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
cd <specific_dir>
git checkout .
```

It will restore all files and directories in current directory which were tracked by git.

Be aware that this will overwrite uncommitted changes to other files in current directory.